# RDP session to headless Ubuntu 22.10 machine disconnects without warning

Tags: ubuntu, rdp

I use windows 10 (fully upto date) rdp to connect to Ubuntu desktop 22.10 running on a HP Microserver gen 8 server running headless.

I can remote in fine. Start doing work (usually with VS Code), terminal, and the Files programs and after some indeterminate time and for some unknown reason I get disconnected and the user has been kicked off the Ubuntu session back to the logon screen. I cannot reconnect using RDP even with the allow logon extension that I installed.

I basically have to use ssh to reboot the server to get back to being able to use rdp. (So Ubuntu is still running.)

I cannot figure out what is causing this disconnect. Is there a log file somewhere that might help me figure it out? It is now becoming more than an irritation.

One thing I did notice when using VS Code the last couple of times was that when duplicating a line of code it decided to keep repeating the duplicate line automatically, I could not get any control back using any key combination I could think off. I use VS Code insiders, but I haven't seen any posts on such an issue, so suspect not VS Code, but perhaps the Ubuntu implementation of the RDP server (RDP desktop being a pretty stable app as far as I know.)

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Sounds like our xrdp is crashing. What's in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the iLO application from HP has a timeout for 30 minutes that I have now disabled and I'm trying to see if this has solved the problem. I'm not using xrdp but the gnome RDP (unless that are the same thing under the hood) thanks for your response